# How to control the inout pin for local controller

Tags: vhdl, fpga

actually I want to make a local controller which will enable the latch. 
As you can seen on my code below, the signal en will take the output from w AND x to enable the latch. After that, w and x will fetch the en. For example, initially, let say the w and x values start at 1, the en will become 1 and cause the latch to fetch data from data_in to data_out. After that, en will become the input of w and x and cause the latch to disable. However, the circuit didn't work when I tested it using university waveform program. The data_out didnt take the value of data_in. I can't figure out what is the problem still I'm new in VHDL. Hope you can assist/advice me on this :) Sorry for my bad english.

```
            library ieee;
            use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
            entity gasp_ctrl is
            port(
                w,x : inout std_logic; --! bidirectional wire
                data_in : in std_logic; --! Data In when latch is enable
                data_out: out std_logic --
            );
            end gasp_ctrl;

            architecture ctrl of gasp_ctrl is
                signal en, ww, xx : std_logic;

            begin
                en <=  w and x; ------ 
                ww <= en;
                xx <= not en;
                w <= ww;
                x <= xx;


                -------- Latch ------
                process(en)
                begin
                    if(en = '1') then
                        data_out <= data_in;
                    end if;
                end process;
            end gasp_ctrl;
```

Comment: Your VHDL code doesn't analyze. The end state for the architecture body should be `end ctrl;` or `end architecture;` or `end architecture ctrl;` instead of `end gasp_ctrl;`.  A mode  `inout` port signal would have a value that is the resolution value between the output value and the value set on the input.  The function you are trying to attribute to these two signals `x` and `w` does not appear practicable without temporally controlling which 'end' drives what value when and you don't appear to be attempting that. It also wouldn't likely be synthesis eligible.

Answer (score 1):

Your code lines form a combinatorial loop:

```
en <=  w and x;
ww <= en;
xx <= not en;
w <= ww;
x <= xx;
```

If you wan't to describe asynchronous gates and delays, then you must instantiate the primitives by hand, otherwise the synthesis compiler will optimize your lines and complain about signal loops.